# Unlock all the sheets in active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to automate this quick code to loop through all the sheet in the active workbook.

For the moment, the code only work on the `Activesheet`:

```
Private Sub Unlockone ()
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet
    .Protect vbNullString, , , , True
    .Range("A1").Copy .Range("A1")
    .Unprotect vbNullString
    .Protect vbNullString, , True, , , , , , , , , , , , , True
    .Unprotect vbNullString
End With
End Sub
```

I tried to do it by myself but had some VBA warning issues and/or the desired output is not reached. Please find below an example of my tries:

```
Private Sub Unlockall()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ActiveSheet
            .Protect vbNullString, , , , True
            .Range("A1").Copy .Range("A1")
            .Unprotect vbNullString
            .Protect vbNullString, , True, , , , , , , , , , , , , True
            .Unprotect vbNullString
        End With
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `With ActiveSheet` for `With WS` in your second code :)

Comment: Try using `With WS` instead.

Comment: I tried to use With WS instead of With Actviesheet and the code is not working.

Comment: I think, the loop has to go and select through all the sheets to activate them each

Comment: No, you don't need to `Select` or `Activate` anything. Exactly what does "is not working" means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good idea to loop through every worksheet and unlock it explicitly. In the code above, it always works with the `ActiveSheet` and although the looping is correct, the `ActiveSheet` is never changed. Thus, try like this:

```
Private Sub UnlockAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            '.Protect vbNullString, userinterfaceonly:=True
            '.Range("A1").Copy .Range("A1")
            .Unprotect "TheRealPasswordHere"
            '.Protect vbNullString, contents:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
            '.Unprotect vbNullString
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

What is even a better idea is to use [named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments) to make the code understandable for maintenance. Thus, instead of:

`.Protect vbNullString, , True, , , , , , , , , , , , , True`

try:

`.Protect vbNullString, contents:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True`

To get the names of the named arguments correctly, just change a bit the commas in the VBEditor and these will show up:
[image]

Comment: Hi Wityaka,
Thanks a lot for your time and answer. I tried the macro and once I have launched it the VBA error #1004 appared saying the password is not valid. If I start the code submitted (activesheet) it work for a single Excel sheet. 
Does the code work in your case ? 
Thanks again
Naxos

Comment: @Naxos - well, the code actually does a few useless stuff, but I thought that it works somehow for you. Anyway, the idea is to have only once `.Unprotect` and 0 times `.Protect`. And furthermore, make sure that the `vbNullString` is changed to some string, which is the actual password.

Comment: @Naxos worksheet passwords are pure annoyance and offer near-zero actual protection (infosec-wise). Consider protecting your sheets without a password - that way you don't have a hard-coded password anywhere in your code, *and* you don't get errors for getting the password wrong.